# CardLayout or Multiple JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I want to make a Java Application which will show different window based on user Interaction. Is it better to use `CardLayout` on `JFrame` or make a `JPanel` for each window then add or remove them on `JFrame`? Which method will have more modularity(means can add different window to increase functionality in App)?

Comment: Another option is a [JTabbedPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html).

Comment: CardLayout (or JTabbedPane) is definitely better than adding and removing the panels manually. CardLayout is more general, it doesn't have the gui to change the panels so you have to change cards programmatically.
 
 

Just one note. When you resize the wrapping component all the cards and/or tabs in it will recieve resize events. They will not perform paint, but if you call some long running method on resize event (like scaling of an image) it will run even if the card/tab is not showing.